# AngularJS: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'this._element.attr')

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS in a project. Users are able to add products to an order and after this order is put together, he can view the order overview. This works great in Chrome but in Safari I get an unexpected error.

> TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'this._element.attr')

Here you can see my code:

**AngularJS**

```
        $scope.order = [];
        $scope.search = "";
        $scope.products = [];
        $scope.categories = [];   


  //ORDER OVERVIEW CHECKOUT
        $scope.modal = function(){
            modal.show();
        };
        $scope.modalhide = function(){
            modal.hide();
        }
        $scope.removeProduct = function(){

        }


    //COMPOSE ORDER ADD/REMOVE/UPDATE 
        $scope.productRemove = function($event, pid){
            $scope.productid = pid;
            if($scope.order.length > 0)
            {
                for(var b = 0; b<$scope.order.length;b++){
                   if($scope.order[b].prodid == pid)
                   {
                       if($scope.order[b].aantal > 1)
                       {
                          $scope.order[b].aantal--;
                          document.getElementById('aantal').innerHTML = document.getElementById('aantal').innerHTML - 1;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           $scope.order.splice(b,1);
                           document.getElementById('aantal').innerHTML = '+';
                           //update quantity in app UI!
                       }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
        $scope.productAdd = function($event,pname, pid, pprice) {
            $scope.pzelfdeid = -1;
            $scope.pzelfde = -1;
            $scope.prodname = pname;
            $scope.prodid = pid;
            $scope.price = pprice;
            if($scope.order.length == 0){
                $scope.order.push({prodid: $scope.prodid, prodname: $scope.prodname, aantal: 1, price: $scope.price, size: 'M', extras: ''});
                $event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 1;
            }        
            else if($scope.order.length > 0){
                for(var b = 0; b<$scope.order.length;b++)
                {
                    if($scope.order[b].prodid == pid)
                    {
                        $scope.pzelfdeid = $scope.order[b].prodid;   
                        $scope.pzelfde = b;
                    }
                }
                if($scope.pzelfde > -1)
                {
                    $scope.order[$scope.pzelfde].aantal++;
                    $event.currentTarget.innerHTML = $scope.order[$scope.pzelfde].aantal;             
                }
                else
                {
                    $scope.order.push({prodid: $scope.prodid, prodname: $scope.prodname, aantal: 1, price: $scope.price, size: 'M', extras: ''});
                    $event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 1;               
                }
            }

        }
    }])
```

**HTML**

```
<ons-modal var="modal">
    <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left"><a href=""; ng-click="modalhide()"><img src="../images/backarrow.png"/></a></div>
        <div class="right"><a href="" ng-click="sendOrder(order)"><i class="fa fa-send fa-fw"></i></a></div>
    </ons-toolbar> 
    <div>
        <div class="left"><p>{{getQuantity()}}</p></div>
        <div class="right"><p>{{getPrice()}}</p></div>
    </div>    
    <ons-list width="100%">
      <ons-list-item class="list-item" ng-repeat="o in order" ng-if="o.length >= 0">
        <ons-carousel swipeable  initial-index="0" auto-scroll>
          <ons-carousel-item class="list-action-item">
            <ons-row>
              <ons-col width="13%">
                <p>{{o.aantal}}</p>
              </ons-col>
              <ons-col width="72%">
                <div class="name">
                    {{o.prodname}}
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    {{o.prodname}}
                </div>
              </ons-col>
            <ons-col width="15%">
                <p>{{o.size}}</p>
            </ons-col>
          </ons-carousel-item>
          <ons-carousel-item class="list-action-menu">
              <p>remove<a ng-click="productRemove($event, o.prodid, o.prodname)"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw" style="color: white"></i></a></p>              
              <p>cancel<i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-fw"></i></p>
          </ons-carousel-item>            
        </ons-carousel>
      </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
    </ons-page>
</ons-modal>
```

At first the order (o) is of course an empty array where the user can add products to. So I think the problem is that `ng-repeat o in order` is trying to get values of an empty array.
It does show the right amount of rows (3 rows if the order consists of 3 products) but it refuses to show the data...
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: did you ever figure this out